# How to process events from the application menu in the renderer

Tags: electron

The main process of an electron application receives the events when a user select a menu option

```js
    const menu = {
        label: 'Foo',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Bar',
                click: () => {
                    // execute function in render process
                },
            },
        ]
    });

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu));
```

and this should execute a function in the render process.

How would I intercept the menu events in the render process or alternatively execute a function in the render process from the main process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a message to the renderer when the menu item is clicked, then do what you want when the renderer receives the message.

This communication is called [IPC, Inter Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#main-and-renderer-processes)

Here's what the menu item would look like:

```js
{
    label: 'Bar',
    click: () => {
        win.webContents.send('menuItemClicked', 'Clicked!');
    },
},
```

Then add this code to your renderer:

```js
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.on('menuItemClicked', function (evt, message)
{
    console.log(message); // Outputs: Clicked!
    
    // Do your renderer stuff here.
});
```

And voila!